# How to teach math handwriting recognition?

Tags: windows-7, handwriting, math-input-panel, handwriting-recognition

Very often Windows does not present me with correct answer to teach.

For example, in following case it does not allow me to enter xi letter:

[image]

Is it possible to do something with this?